# "She is going to tell everyone that I stole her money." - the that-clause does not necessarily have to be true, right?

Tags: meaning-in-context

**Example 1:**

> She is going to tell everyone **that I stole her money**.

This that-clause in **Example 1** does not have to be true, am I right?

I think it can be something that is true or something that has been made up.

**Example 2**

> A: She is going to tell everyone **that I stole her money**. It wasn't me.

> B: Yeah, you were with me at that time. It couldn't be you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such a clause does not assert that the stament is true, merely that she will say it. She might think it is true, or might be intentionally lying, the statement does not say. Even example 2 does not say.

Such a sentence can include an obvious falsity as in:

> She is going to tell everyone that the earth is flat.

It can be a future statement whose truth no one yet knows, such as:

> She is going to tell everyone that Jane Jones will win the next election.